# Azure Data Factory v2 - OData to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory

I have set up an oData to Cosmos DB Pipeline in Azure Data Factory v2.

I was using this service to test out the functionality:
http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/

I am mapping one string field to another but I keep receiving the following error:

```
{
"errorCode": "1000",
"message": "ErrorCode=SystemErrorStageDefTypeNotMatch,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An internal error occurred when building stages for transfer. The input and output type of stage definition do not match.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
"failureType": "SystemError",
"target": "Copy_oDataTest"
}
```

Comment: were you able to get this to work? I am running into same issue while migrating data to data lake?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I ended up looking at Logic Apps to perform the same sort of functionality

Comment: Thanks for responding. In my case it was issue with a join in one of the dynamic queries we were building Hope this helps.

Comment: For my case, the issue was with copy_data activity, sink - "auto create table" enabled option. In any case table exist or not I was getting author mentioned error. After disabling the error gone. Keep in mind in same cases "auto create table" is a must. At least you will know what causing the error.